# Proving that the total variation of an absolutely continuous function is absolutely continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am trying to prove this statement which appears in the real analysis text by Stein which he just passes as a remark.

If $F$ is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$, then the total variation of $F$ is continuous and to be specific, absolutely continuous.

I believe that it suffices to show that the total variation of $F$ is absolutely continuous.

The total variation of $F$ on $[a,x]$ is defined to be $T_F(x)=\sup\sum_{j=1}^N|F(t_j)-F(t_{j-1})|$ where the $\sup$ is over all partitions of $[a,x].$ Does this mean that I have to prove that $\sum_{k=1}^N|T_F(b_k)-T(a_k)|<\epsilon$ if $\sum_{k=1}^N(b_k -a_k)<\delta?$

This looks a bit strange to me...can anyone clarify this matter? thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, basically that is what you have to prove. What makes the proof more manageable is the additive property of the total variation,

$$T_F(c) - T_F(b) = T_{F\lvert_{[b,c]}}(c) = \sup \left\lbrace \sum_{i=1}^n \lvert F(x_i) - F(x_{i-1})\rvert : b = i_0 < i_1 < \dotsb < i_n = c;\; n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\right\rbrace$$

for $b < c$.

The proof becomes still shorter if you know that a function is absolutely continuous iff it is an integral, and if

$$F(x) = F(a) + \int_a^x f(t)\,dt,$$

then

$$T_F(x) = \int_a^x \lvert f(t)\rvert\,dt.$$

Comment: Hi, may I ask how you got that if $F(X)= F(a)+ \int_a^x f(t) dt$, then $T_F(x)= \int_a^x|f(t) |dt$ ? Thank you!